Getting this FormatException: Invalid double when parsing a string to double
I am trying to convert a string to a double by using the double.parse() method. When I use this, I am getting this error:
FormatException: Invalid double
This is the value of salePriceController.text: $4,249,000.00
Here is the code for what I am doing:
class CommissionCalculatorPopup {
  static void showCommissionCalculator(BuildContext context, double salePrice) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CommissionCalculatorDialog(salePrice: salePrice);
      },
    );
  }
}

class CommissionCalculatorDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final double salePrice;

  const CommissionCalculatorDialog({required this.salePrice, super.key});

  @override
  State<CommissionCalculatorDialog> createState() =>
      _CommissionCalculatorDialogState();
}

class _CommissionCalculatorDialogState
    extends State<CommissionCalculatorDialog> {
  TextEditingController salePriceController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController commissionRateController = TextEditingController();
  double commission = 0.0;

  final NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.currency(symbol: '\$');
  String _formatCurrency(String textCurrency) {

    /// Format the contract price
    String numericCurrency = textCurrency.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\d]'), '');
    if (numericCurrency.isNotEmpty) {
      double value = double.parse(numericCurrency);
      String formattedText = currencyFormatter.format(value);
      if (formattedText != null) {
        return formattedText;
      } else {
        return "\$0.00";
      }
    } else {
      return "\$0.00";
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    salePriceController.text = _formatCurrency(widget.salePrice.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        'Commission Calculator',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.sp),
      ),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: salePriceController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Sale Price (\$)'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: commissionRateController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Commission Rate (%)'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.sp),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: calculateCommission,
            child: const Text('Calculate Commission'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.sp),
          Text(
            //'Commission: $_formatCurrency(commission.toString())',
            'Commission: \$${commission.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.sp),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: const Text('Close'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void calculateCommission() {
    if (salePriceController.text.isNotEmpty &&
        commissionRateController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      try {
        double salePrice = double.parse(salePriceController.text) ?? 0.0; <<<< ERROR HERE
        double commissionRate = double.parse(commissionRateController.text) ?? 0.0;

        double commissionAmount = (salePrice * commissionRate) / 100;
        setState(() {
          commission = commissionAmount;
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      // Handle empty fields
      // You can show an error message or take appropriate action
    }
  }
}

The error occurs in the calculateCommission method. I am not sure why this is happening but I think it has to do with the original assignment of salePriceController but I am just not seeing the issue.
Thanks for your help.

The $ and , are not valid in the normal string representations of doubles.  Since you use NumberFormat.format to generate the string, you should be using NumberFormat.parse when reading it back.

Yep, your calculator is working fine. But is not accepting number like 3,200.00. So you need to Show numbers like that but use in calculations numbers like 3200.00. You can use String.replace(",", "");

Thanks for your comments. I was able to fix it because I had a type mismatch with the variable "commission".

You need to declare it in your code:
 late String _workingValue; 

And inside your calculateCommission()
      void calculateCommission() {  
    
        if (salePriceController.text.isNotEmpty &&
            commissionRateController.text.isNotEmpty) {
          try {
    
            _workingValue = salePriceController.text.toString().replaceAll(',', '');
    
            double salePrice = double.parse(_workingValue);//double.parse(salePriceController.text) ?? 0.0; //<<<< ERROR HERE
            double commissionRate = double.parse(commissionRateController.text) ?? 0.0;
    
            double commissionAmount = (salePrice * commissionRate) / 100;
            setState(() {
              commission = commissionAmount;
            });
          }catch (e){
    
          }
    
          }
        }

Do the samething if you will earn commissions greater than 1000. 

The error occurs because the string you are trying to parse ($4,249,000.00) contains characters like the dollar sign ($) and commas (,) that are not valid in a numeric format. To convert this string to a double, you need to preprocess it to remove any non-numeric characters except the decimal point.
Solution:
String salePriceText = salePriceController.text;
String cleanedText = salePriceText.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^0-9.]'), '');
double salePrice = double.parse(cleanedText);

